# Function of 2 variables is not differentiable at origin but when described parametrically it is?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the equation
$$
f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \textrm{, }\textrm{ }\textrm{ } f(0,0)=0 \textrm{, }\textrm{ }\textrm{ } \textrm{when } (x,y)\neq(0,0) \textrm{, }\textrm{ }\textrm{ } f(x, y) = \dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}
$$
And I rewrite the equation as,
$$
f(x,y) = f(0,0) +xf_x(0,0)+yf_y(0,0)+R(x,y)\\
\text{where, } f_x(0,0) = 1 \text{, and, } f_y(0,0)=0
$$
Then I can show it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ by proving that,
$$
\lim\dfrac{R(x,y)}{|(x,y)|}\neq0 \text{ as } |(x,y)| \rightarrow(0,0)
$$
If take the limit along the line $(x,y) = (x,x)$ then we get
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{-x^3/{2x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+x^2}} = \dfrac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\neq0
$$
Thus it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, but if we describe $f$ parametrically, i.e. $(x,y)=(at,yt)$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants
$$
f(x,y)=f(at,bt)=\dfrac{a^3t^3}{a^2t^2+b^2t^2} =\dfrac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}t
$$
Then clearly $f_t(at,bt)$ exists, $f_t = \dfrac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$ but if we take $a=b$ then does this not just follow the same line as $(x,y) = (x,x)$ which we just showed previously is not differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

You correctely proved that $f$ is not differentiable. But it is continuous, which is not a contradiction, since a functions can be continuous and not differentiable.

When you use the parametrization $(at,bt)$ on $f$ you've just restricted it on this path, that is, if $\alpha(t)=(at,bt)$, then you are considering the function $h(t)=f(\alpha(t))=\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}t$, which is a diferentiable function of one variable, as you proved by deriving $h'(t)=\frac
{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$. It means that, if you compose a non-diferentiable function $f$ with a diferentiable function, you can have a differentiable function. In other words, although $f$ is not differentiable, it is differentiable along some paths.

Besides that, pay attention that when you proved $f$ is not differentiable, you used the path $(x,x)$ on $\frac{R(x,x)}{|(x,y)|}$ which is different from use the same path over $f_t$.